# Dynamics NAV 2009 Classic Client Extensions

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2009

I am curious if it is possible to extend the Microsoft Dynamics Nav Classic Client and program an add-on that can for example enhance the Object Designer.

For example in the "Object Designer" it is not possible to do batch updates to several objects at one, for example changing the last modification date and time.

It would be nice to write a small extension for Dynamics NAV that can do this. Any links or information that can help me to get started are very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [Codeunit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd301168.aspx) which can batch update the Object table and update the modification date field. You can then write your own [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd354921.aspx) (or form if you are using only C/SIDE) with a button to invoke the codeunit. You could, for example, set filters on that page to determine which objects are updated.

If you want to import and export objects, it is a little tougher. In NAV 2013 you can use the [command line interface for C/SIDE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nav/archive/2013/01/28/new-finsql-exe-command-line.aspx). In earlier versions, I think the only way to do this is to use CFront which can [import and export FOB files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nav/archive/2008/04/19/importing-and-exporting-nav-objects-with-c-front.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is Possible for dynamics Nav 2009

1. Create a table having the fields `objID, Name , Last Run Date` or any other fields according to your requirments
2. Create a master codeunit in which you call your all objects you entered in table
3. Than create a windows Service and set a time interval after how much time you want to run your master code
4. Install this service in your server and it will run automatically after specified interval
5. To install this service you have to run VS2013 or greater developer command prompt as an admin
6. To Install your service reach the directory of release windows service folder e.g
7. *C:\Users\Defualtuser\source\repos\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Release*
8. And Write this command: `Installutil YourServiceName.exe`
9. Then open the services as an admin and start your service

Your objects will update automatically.